# navigation menu with defined css classes, breaks when I add ID attribute to li tags

Tags: html, css

Ive got a navigation menu that displays an unordered <ul> list on my site. Im trying to add in some additional parameters to it so i can control the output of it via js as i want some things to display sometimes vs other times to have them hidden.

The issue is, the output comes out quite nicely provided I dont apply any id attributes on the <li> tags, as soon as i do, it makes the layout stretch and appear to add padding to it automatically.

```
<div id="navigation">
<ul id="jsddm" class="dbtree">
    <li class="is-current" id="SHOP">
        <a href="...">SHOP</a>
        <ul>
            <li id="JEWELLERY">
                <a href="...">JEWELLERY</a>
                <ul>
                    <li id="NECKLACES"><a href="...">NECKLACES</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <li id="RINGS"><a href="...">RINGS</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <li id="EARRINGS"><a href="...">EARRINGS</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <li id="FRIENDSHIP BRACELETS"><a href="...">FRIENDSHIP BRACELETS</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <li id="CHARM BRACELETS"><a href="...">CHARM BRACELETS</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li id="BESPOKE"><a href="...">BESPOKE</a>
                <ul>
                    <li id="MAKE YOUR BESPOKE "><a href="...">MAKE YOUR BESPOKE</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <li id="CHAINS"><a href="...">CHAINS</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <li id="LETTERS"><a href="...">LETTERS</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <li id="CRYSTALS"><a href="...">CRYSTALS</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <li id="GEMSTONES"><a href="...">GEMSTONES</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <li id="CHARMS"><a href="...">CHARMS</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <li id="COLOURED CORD"><a href="...">COLOURED CORD</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li id="KA FINES (coming soon)"><a href="...">KA FINES (coming soon)</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li id="GIFT VOUCHER"><a href="...">GIFT VOUCHER</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li id="MY DETAILS"><a href="...">MY DETAILS</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li id="MY HISTORY"><a href="...">MY HISTORY</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li id="LOGOUT"><a href="...">LOGOUT</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li id="BESPOKE">
        <a href="...">BESPOKE</a>
        <ul>
            <li id="ABOUT"><a href="...">ABOUT</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li id="LOOKBOOK "><a href="...">LOOKBOOK</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li id="MAKE YOUR BESPOKE"><a href="...">MAKE YOUR BESPOKE</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li id="LOOKBOOK "><a href="...">LOOKBOOK</a>
        <ul>
            <li id="BESPOKE LOOKBOOK"><a href="...">BESPOKE LOOKBOOK</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li id="SOMETHING LIKE PARADISE"><a href="...">SOMETHING LIKE PARADISE</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li id="OUR STORY"><a href="...">OUR STORY</a></li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li id="PRESS"><a href="...">PRESS</a></li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li id="BLOG"><a href="...">BLOG</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

as soon as I add `id="SHOP"` to the very first <li> (`<div id="navigation"><ul id="jsddm" class="dbtree"><li class="is-current" id="SHOP">`), it breaks it by making additional padding, its like it ignores the original rules in the stylesheet.

CSS:-

```
<style>
   #navigation
   {
    width:160px;
    float:left;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-family:'BulmerMTStd-Regular';
    line-height:18px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
    font-size:12px; 
    }
    #navigation ul{margin-left:0px; padding-left:0px;}
    #navigation li{text-align:left; margin:0px; padding:0px;}
    #navigation ul li{color:#000000; list-style:none; margin-left:0px; padding-left:0px; margin-top:0px;}
    #navigation li ul{margin-left:0px; padding-left:0px; display:none;}
    #navigation li a{color:#000000;font-family:'BulmerMTStd-Regular'; text-decoration:none; line-     height:18px; padding-bottom:10px;}
    #navigation li a:hover{color:#8a8888;}
    #navigation li ul li ul{padding-left:10px; color:#8a8888;}
    #navigation li ul li ul a{color:#8a8888;}
    #navigation li ul li ul a:hover{color:#000000;}
    #navigation{z-index:0}
    </style>
```

Im sure this is probably a really simple issue... but i cant seem to resolve it.. any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your CSS above is only for the navigation ID and its sub-classes.  By adding a new ID to the elements in your list here, they no longer apply to your CSS.  You will have to add in CSS to include the newly specified id tags.

Comment: 1) Which browser(s) are you having this problem in? 2) Simply adding an ID cannot have effect on display, unless there is CSS targeting those IDs. An easy way to find out what CSS is being applied is to open Google Chrome, right-click the element in question (which opens the developer tools pane), and examine its "computed style" in the bottom-right of the developer tools pane. Of course, this can also be done in any browser with developer tools. Do you see any CSS targeting those ID's in that list?

Comment: Is the browser rendering in standards mode (and not in quirks mode)? Does your page pass HTML (http://validator.w3.org/) and CSS validators (http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/)?

Comment: Also, keep in mind the rules for id's in html. In particular you can't use spaces (http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Dchris says, the only change between the two is the addition of `id="SHOP"`, which as @smclark says will only affect things if you've defined some styles for #SHOP somewhere.

While we're at it, your lists are unnecessarily deeply nested. You can make the HTML cleaner and more legible (and in your example much shorter) by changing

```
<li>
    asfasf
    <ul>
        lkhlkhlkh
    </ul>
</li>
```

to

```
<li>asfasf</li>
<ul>
    lkhlkhlkh
</ul>
```

The result is

```
    <div id="navigation">   
    <ul id="jsddm" class="dbtree">
        <li class="is-current" id="SHOP"><a href="...">SHOP</a></li>
        <ul>
            <li id="JEWELLERY"><a href="...">JEWELLERY</a></li>
            <ul>
                <li id="NECKLACES"><a href="...">NECKLACES</a></li>
                <li id="RINGS"><a href="...">RINGS</a></li>
                <li id="EARRINGS"><a href="...">EARRINGS</a></li>
                <li id="FRIENDSHIP BRACELETS"><a href="...">FRIENDSHIP BRACELETS</a></li>
                <li id="CHARM BRACELETS"><a href="...">CHARM BRACELETS</a></li>
            </ul>
            <li id="BESPOKE"><a href="...">BESPOKE</a></li>
            <ul>
                <li id="MAKE YOUR BESPOKE "><a href="...">MAKE YOUR BESPOKE</a></li>
                <li id="CHAINS"><a href="...">CHAINS</a></li>
                <li id="LETTERS"><a href="...">LETTERS</a></li>
                <li id="CRYSTALS"><a href="...">CRYSTALS</a></li>
                <li id="GEMSTONES"><a href="...">GEMSTONES</a></li>
                <li id="CHARMS"><a href="...">CHARMS</a></li>
                <li id="COLOURED CORD"><a href="...">COLOURED CORD</a></li>
            </ul>
            <li id="KA FINES (coming soon)"><a href="...">KA FINES (coming soon)</a></li>
            <li id="GIFT VOUCHER"><a href="...">GIFT VOUCHER</a></li>
            <li id="MY DETAILS"><a href="...">MY DETAILS</a></li>
            <li id="MY HISTORY"><a href="...">MY HISTORY</a></li>
            <li id="LOGOUT"><a href="...">LOGOUT</a></li>
        </ul>
        <li id="BESPOKE"><a href="...">BESPOKE</a></li>
        <ul>
            <li id="ABOUT"><a href="...">ABOUT</a></li>
            <li id="LOOKBOOK "><a href="...">LOOKBOOK</a></li>
            <li id="MAKE YOUR BESPOKE"><a href="...">MAKE YOUR BESPOKE</a></li>
        </ul>
        <li id="LOOKBOOK "><a href="...">LOOKBOOK</a></li>
        <ul>
            <li id="BESPOKE LOOKBOOK"><a href="...">BESPOKE LOOKBOOK</a></li>
            <li id="SOMETHING LIKE PARADISE"><a href="...">SOMETHING LIKE PARADISE</a></li>
        </ul>
        <li id="OUR STORY"><a href="...">OUR STORY</a></li>
        <li id="PRESS"><a href="...">PRESS</a></li>
        <li id="BLOG"><a href="...">BLOG</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Of course, you'll need to adjust your CSS, but that'll clean up too - no more `ul li li ul ul`-type definitions. Again, while we're at it the CSS can be cleaned and trimmed. A couple pointers: `#navigation li` styles will target *all* <li> within #navigation, so for example they're  applied to `#navigation ul li`. Something like this should give you the same result (may have a typo and/or accidentally deleted definition or two). The indentation is just to help you visualize the cascade (CSS isn't typically presented like this, but it doesn't make a difference). Note that this is for your deeply-nested, <ul>s inside <li>s structure.

```
<style type="text/css">
#navigation {
    width:160px;
    float:left;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-family:'BulmerMTStd-Regular';
    line-height:18px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
    font-size:12px;
    z-index: 0;}

    #navigation ul{margin-left:0px; padding-left:0px;}

        #navigation ul li{color:#000000; list-style:none;}

    #navigation li{text-align:left; margin:0px; padding:0px;}

        #navigation li ul{display:none;}
        #navigation li a{color:#000000; text-decoration:none;}
        #navigation li a:hover{color:#8a8888;}

            #navigation li ul li ul{padding-left:10px; color:#8a8888;}

                #navigation li ul li ul a{color:#8a8888;}
                #navigation li ul li ul a:hover{color:#000000;}
</style>
```

Comment: Hi Henry, thanks for this, I really like your take on this. very much appreciated. Only issue for us, is we are using a very old function that retrieves everything from a database and we have no access to change the actual HTML that is generated. I will keep this reference for future adjustments when we are allowed to create a new function to generate the HTML, greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

In the second part of html code you added  id="SHOP". Then the li tag chooses the  id="SHOP" first.The li tag will use any property from id="jsddm"if and only if there are different properties from the id="SHOP".If there are same properties in those two ids then the one from id="SHOP"  will be applied.

Generally, try not to mixing up lots of classes and ids in inline elements.